Unable to open the initiating thread's primary token in a Windows mini-filter driver
I'm intending to retrieve the username associated with the primary token of the thread that has initiated an I/O operation. To do that, I use the security API. First, I use ObOpenObjectByPointer to get the HANDLE to the thread object itself:
    status = ObOpenObjectByPointer(
    callback_data->Thread, // FLT_CALLBACK_DATA.Thread
    OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE,
    0,
    READ_CONTROL,
    0,
    KernelMode,
    &hThread
);

Then ZwOpenThreadTokenEx is called to get the HANDLE to the token itself:
    status = ZwOpenThreadTokenEx(
    hThread,
    READ_CONTROL,
    TRUE,  // To perform access check with process's or thread's context
    OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE,
    &hToken
);

Subsequent calls are made to ZwQueryInformationToken and SecLookupAccountSid to finally get the PUNICODE_STRING to the account's name.
ObOpenObjectByPointer works fine. The problem is that ZwOpenThreadTokenEx returns STATUS_NO_TOKEN.

STATUS_NO_TOKEN: An attempt has been made to open a token associated with a thread that is not currently impersonating a client.

Am I using the wrong solution to retrieve a HANDLE to the primary token? Is there any better solution (Both for my general intention and the way token is retrieved).

Maybe this example will help: https://github.com/jsecurity101/JonMon/blob/13a15714f0a9e53a14119b14033e3026dd81f09e/JonMon/token.cpp#L5
